# Objective c unicode char* to NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm getting char* with latin letter
print example : M\xe4da Primavesi

i'm trying to convert it to NSString , the final result should be Mäda Primavesi.

Anyone know how the conversation be done ?

Thanks

Comment: To all you guys thinking this look like UTF-8: No, it's not. I will not downvote, but your answers are just fast and  wrong. Please be careful when posting answers.

Comment: Is your string encoded within the app or does it get sent from somewhere else like a server? My answer below explains some gotcha's from your \x escaping.

Answer (score 1):

The encoding you want is `NSISOLatin1StringEncoding`:

```
NSString *latin = [NSString stringWithCString:"M\xe4da Primavesi" encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
```

**BUT** you will notice that this prints `MÚ Primavesi`. That is because `\x` is greedy, and interprets the `"da"` as part of the hex `\xe4da`. You have to find a way to separate the `"\xe4"` part with the `"da"` part.

This works:

```
NSString *latin = [NSString stringWithCString:"M\xe4""da Primavesi" encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding]; // prints Mäda Primavesi
```

I suggest you encode your latin C-String using utf-8 string `"M\u00e4da Primavesi"` instead, and decode it with `NSUTF8StringEncoding`.

Comment: In the "greedy2 part you have \xefda instead of \xe4da. Please correct, I cannot edit (1 char only)

Answer (score 0):

Try the `NSString` API `stringWithCString:encoding:` as below,

```
`[NSString stringWithCString:cString encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    char *latinChars = "M\xe4da Primavesi";
    NSString *chatStr = [NSString stringWithCString:latinChars encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"chatStr:%@", chatStr);
```

The result is:MÚ Primavesi

And I have a try:

```
char *latinChars = "M\xe4 da Primavesi"; //add an blank for 'da'
        NSString *chatStr = [NSString stringWithCString:latinChars encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"chatStr:%@", chatStr);
```

The result is:Mä da Primavesi

Comment: @iMani so I show the result is my NSLog, the final result is decided by NSStringEncoding. I just not try all the enum values

Comment: ASCII is 7-bit and does not contain E4. You got correct result only by coincidence. Real encoding is latin1.

Answer (score 0):

Look like latin1.

```
[NSString stringWithCString:cString encoding: NSISOLatin1StringEncoding]
```